# Web address of .url files in Sharepoint Online document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

When we add "Link" files to the Sharepoint document library, how can we edit/display the original web address of these .URL files?

Currently, I can only see it when I click on the URL.

Comment: As per this article there seems to be no other way. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/editing-a-link-in-a-document-library/m-p/207095

Answer (score 0):

Per my test and knowledge, URL files created in the document library cannot be edited. You could click Copy link to check the link of URL file.